# Stop MySql InnoDB truncate on reboot

Tags: mysql, innodb, truncate

How can I stop a truncate of a MySql innodb?

When I restart the database it tries to continue the truncating which leads to the problem of the log group capacity exceeding. To increase this limit it is necessary to shut down the db clean which is not possible because it always tries to start the truncation again.

As a last resort I can go into recovery mode 6 but want to avoid it cause of the high possibility of corrupted data.

mysql error log:

```
2019-11-21T08:11:36.399109Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22770004328925
2019-11-21T08:11:36.401772Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2019-11-21T08:11:36.401778Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2019-11-21T08:11:36.405507Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The age of the last checkpoint is 90601444, which exceeds the log group capacity 90593280.
2019-11-21T08:11:36.524771Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 106 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 106 row operations to undo
2019-11-21T08:11:36.524799Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 31970042624
2019-11-21T08:11:36.524806Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
2019-11-21T08:11:41.069233Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2019-11-21T08:11:41.069274Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 848320890, file name mysql-bin.006993
2019-11-21T08:11:41.200977Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completing truncate for table with id (1988) residing in file-per-table tablespace with id (2019)
2019-11-21T08:11:58.338120Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The age of the last checkpoint is 90622848, which exceeds the log group capacity 90593280.
```

Comment: I doubt if `TRUNCATE TABLE` can be stopped by a reboot -- it is too fast.

Comment: it shouldn't happen by default unless there's a script that does that when mysql service was restarted.